# Big-O Time Complexity in ListInterator<String> methods

Tags: java, iterator

I have been trying to study up on time complexity lately and while going through Interators and ListInterator I came across a few simple methods and I just wanted to make sure I was getting this correct because I am not too confident about it.

```
MyListIterator iter = list2.listIterator(); //this is not full code but list2.size() == n

for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
   list2.add(0, "x");
}
//I believe this is O(n)


for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
   list2.add("x"); 
}
//I think this is O(1) but maybe O(n)?


while(iter.hasNext()){ 
   iter.next();
   iter.remove();
}
//I believe this is O(n) bc of shifting
```

Comment: Good to hear you are studying! your question is missing

Comment: The second one, you have a loop counting to *n*. It's goig to be at least *O(n)* (presumably *O(n)* unless you have a really weird implementation of `add`. And the last should be *O(n)* because it goes around the loop *n* times.

Comment: So they are all just O(n) then I would assume

Comment: *I have been trying to study up* Do. Or do not. There is no try. --- **Master Yoda**

Comment: @AndrewWilken Unless there's a `ConcurrentModificationException` or similar issue.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Is there any chance the last one could be O(n^2)?

Comment: @AndrewWilken Implemented reasonably, `hasNext` ,`next` and `remove` should have linear time for a linked list. Array list would be different, unless double-ended.